# css hover not applying in codepen

Tags: css, svg

following a tutorial from udemy, i seem to be doing everything according to the video but it isnt working. i have an svg twitter icon. it contains the twitter bird and a circle around it. what is suppose to happen on hover is the circle disappears using hover and transform with the scale property but it wont disappear. anyone know whats wrong?

https://codepen.io/cole-pratt/pen/poJJdzy?editors=1100

```
.twitter-icon-group:hover {
  .twitter-outline {
    transform: scale(0);
  }
}
```

Comment: Change the CSS Preprocessor to SCSS

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Answer (score 1):

You're writing SASS, but the CSS pane isn't processing it as such. In codepen on the css pane, select the cog and Choose "SCSS" for the CSS Preprocessor. Then it works as it should.

Answer (score 0):

This is just a issue with the hierarchy of how you scale the actual outline. Instead of just placing it inside a parenthesis, this is the correct syntax.

```
.twitter-icon-group:hover > .twitter-outline {
   transform: scale(0);                                                                
}
```

Its easier to imagine as 'Object you want to observe':hover > 'what you want to affect' {'what you want to happen'}.